# How can i verify the label which is displayed in UI (only for 5 second)s and appears when there is an error in the page load using selenium python?

Tags: python, selenium

If i load a page and there are some errors in the page and there will be a message which appears for 5 to 10 seconds with the message "error updating data". How can i check if on page load this error exists or not? Developer had given me the id of this label and it starts with span.

Im expected to check if this label occurs on page load using selenium and python. Basically checking if there are any errors in the page on loading. We have around 20 to 30 pages, so have to check each page is loaded without any error

[Error updating data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1PZKX.png)

Comment: What have you tried so far?  If you are new to Selenium you'll need to get familiar with that first. https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/

Answer (score 0):

If you want to check multiple pages it really depends on what type of page list are you trying to check.

If it's a list of pages such as "https://qwant.com" and then "https://duckduckgo.com" you probably want to iterate through them in a loop with each iteration having an unique .get request. In this case it depends on how do you store the list of links. If it's in a simple list you can easily use .get for each url in the list. Let's suppose that you have a list of links stored in the "urls" list. So :

```
# Your urls list
urls = ["https://qwant.com", "https://duckduckgo.com", "https://startpage.com"]
```

Then you would iterate through each link in the list with a for loop :

```
for url in urls:
    driver.get(url)
    # Do the actions that you need here
```

Now to the message id check. You haven't provided the ID so I am not sure if the ID is a simple ID, or a XPath for instance. However you can use both depending on which one do you have. We of course want to wait and see if the message pops up on the page. It's important to note however that if the message does not appear you would get the TimeoutException and your program would be terminated. To prevent this you want to use try and except to see whether the message comes up.

To do this first you would want to introduce a WebDriverWait with time specified for how long Selenium should wait until looking for the element. We can define WebDriverWait like this :

```
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 20)
```

In this case "driver" is the name of WebDriver that you define somewhere in the code above.

Then you would want to wait until the element comes up. You would use the new wait method to wait for it to come up. In case of a simple ID you would do :

```
wait.until(ec.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, "element-id")))
```

You have mentioned that the ID contains span which leads me to believe that you may have been given an XPath identifier. If that's the case simply modify the code to search for an XPath with that ID :

```
wait.until(ec.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//span[@id="element-id"]")))
```

However if the text in the error box is unique and you are unsure about the ID you could also search for the text of the error itself :

```
wait.until(ec.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//span[contains(text(), 'Error updating data')]")))
```

Now as I mentioned in the beginning since you are supposed to check if an error exists it is expected that sometimes it might not. To prevent the TimeoutException from happening you would want to wrap the code in an try/except statement to check whether it actually exists and if not skip it. And so you would do something like :

```
try:
    wait.until(ec.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//span[contains(text(), 'Error updating data')]")))
except TimeoutException:
    pass
```

Though it is important to note that for this to work your project needs to have the Selenium Exceptions library imported as so :

```
from selenium.common.exceptions import WebDriverException, TimeoutException
```

The same applies for the WebDriverWait we used at the beginning that would be :

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
```

With all of this said your final code could look something like this :

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as ec
from selenium.common.exceptions import TimeoutException

# Define WebDriver and WebDriverWait here
driver = webdriver.Firefox(executable_path="/geckdriver")
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 20)

# Your urls list
urls = ["https://qwant.com", "https://duckduckgo.com", "https://startpage.com"]

# Iterate through every page in the urls list
for url in urls:
    driver.get(url)
    try:
    wait.until(ec.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//span[contains(text(), 'Error updating data')]")))
    print(f"Error code found on page {url}")

except TimeoutException:
    pass
```